# jQuery slider working on all browsers except Chrome 15. Works again when resizing Chrome 15 browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently doing some work on http://www.windjammerandtruck.com/windjammer 
You have to click the first peice of text and then a gallery (Let's say Rocket Science on the right). The slider which will appear **works in all browsers except Chrome 15**. 
The **weird thing is that if you resize the browser window or open the Chrome debugger then the slider will automatically work**. This is very strange.

I have checked all W3C validation errors and it seems the problem is not related to them.
I have checked the JS also.

Did you have similar problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write what you want to be in chrome within this:

---

```
/*Chrome and Opera only */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) 
{
    #myId { color:red; }
}
```